# Late Loading a .net plugin dll

Tags: c#, dll, compact-framework, plugins, c#-2.0

I have a C# .Net 2.0CF application where I would like to load a .NET 'plug-in' DLL at runtime.

As I understand it, I should be able to use the `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom()` to load the DLL to an Assembly. Then use `Assembly.GetTypes()` to get the list of types within the plugin to match them to my expected interfaces.

The problem is that when I call `GetTypes()`, I get a `System.TypeLoadException()`. Based on the exception message, I assume this is because this particular plugin references some other assembly that this program knows nothing about. But, that's part of the point of it being a plugin! I don't want my application to have to know anything about these other assemblies.

How can I load this plug-in DLL without having my application reference every assembly used in the plugin?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: You don't have to have your application *reference* every assembly used in the plugin, but you'll probably need to have it load them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is not that your app should reference every assembly that a plug-in uses. The plug-in *references* another DLL, not your app, and the plug-in should be "installed" (maybe simply put in a directory) along with everything it needs. This is unavoidable.

Comment: That was it. One of the plug-in DLL's dependencies were missing.
Thanks!