# Dealing with multiple versions of a single c# dll (plugin)

Tags: c#, plugins, versioning

I have a challenge similar to [creating-my-own-plug-ins-for-my-own-project-in-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387685/creating-my-own-plug-ins-for-my-own-project-in-c) and [late-loading-a-net-plugin-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390327/late-loading-a-net-plugin-dll), with the added headache of being able to specify a version to use. My current idea is to simply use console apps, with folders named by version. I'd then find the folder and load the console app by known name, using `Process`.

I'd like to avoid having to write out and read in text, which is the only real way I can see for a console app to talk to my 'control' windows forms app. Using dlls seems like a possibility, but I haven't done much with dynamic loading before and it seems rather messy either way.

I've had a quick look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF), but it's still under development, and aiming for .Net 4.0, which I might be able to look at, although I need this solution relatively quickly.

Any other ideas out there for accessing a specific version?

Comment: MEF, I think, is a good option, and works with VS2008 & .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I did have a play around with MEF, but in the end using console apps was just much easier. With the added benefit of being able to run using only arguments - which has turned out to be very handy in a Windows Compute Cluster Job Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used a well-known folder structure to contain different versions of console apps.

No, it's not clean, and probably not the best way to do it. However, I don't have control over the console apps/dlls, and this works without being too much to explain to the researchers I work with. They know research, C# is just a tool.